# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pycbc_core: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, couchbase

I have install couchbase version 4.0.2.While trying to use "from couchbase.cluster import Cluster" in python I am getting DLL load failed error.I am new to couchbase.Any suggestions on how to fix error are welcome.Sofar I have created a virtual environment then install six, future and then couchbase libraries.

Comment: do you really mean Couchbase Server 4.0.2 (which is a very old release), or is that just the version of the Couchbase Python SDK you're using?

Comment: I am using couchbase sdk 4.0.2

Comment: and which version of Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: Thanks for helping, all of you.I have raised a ticket with couchbase support team because it is not working on my system.Tried with friends as well getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From [Couchbase documentation Windows Quick Install](https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html)

> Starting with Python 3.11.5, Windows builds from python.org now use OpenSSL 3.0. If using a version prior to 4.1.9 of the Python SDK, a potential side-effect of this change is an ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pycbc_core error. Upgrade the SDK to a version >= 4.1.9 to avoid this side-effect. If unable to upgrade, a work-around is to set the PYCBC_OPENSSL_DIR environment variable to the path where the OpenSSL 1.1 libraries (libssl-1_1.dll and libcrypto-1_1.dll) can be found.